# Print only the rightmost part of a string

Tags: c, string

I am applying printf and/or other functions to a certain string of characters, read from a file. I want to skip the first 5 characters under certain conditions. Now I thought to be clever by, if the conditions apply, increasing the string pointer by 5:

```
 if (strlen(nav_code) == 10 ) {nav_code = 5+nav_code;}
```

but the compiler refuses this:

> error: assignment to expression with array type

What have I misunderstood? How to make my idea work - or is it a bad idea anyway?

Comment: You should start with study C array (especially strings). After that you can make 'difficult' operations like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably becuase `nav_code` is not a pointer but a character array like `char nav_code[50]`. Try the following:

```
char nav_code[50];
char *nav_code_ptr = nav_code;
if (strlen(nav_code_ptr) == 10 ) {nav_code_ptr += 5;}
// forth on, use nav_code_ptr instead of nav_code
```

Comment: Stephan, thanks, and apologies for not documenting the nature of nav_code; it is declared exactly like you assume. Excuse my ignorance but how does your solution go on? I.e. where I formerly wrote     printf("%s\n",nav_code) how do I apply nav_code_ptr ?

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for patient explanation, Jonathan Livingstone Seagull has been learning again ;)

Answer (score 1):

> I am applying printf and/or other functions to a certain string of characters, read from a file. I want to skip the first 5 characters under certain conditions.

If `printf` is all what you need, then sure you can skip the first 5 characters.

Given `nav_code` is string (either char array or char pointer), then:

```
printf( "%s", nav_code + 5 );  // skip the first 5 characters
```

Of course you need to make sure your string has more than 5 characters, otherwise it's flat out illegal as out-of-bound access.

Comment: That does work but is not useful in this particular situation, because the "right truncation" is only applied under certain conditions. That is why I seek to modify the pointer before applying it to a function.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `nav_code` is an array and arrays cannot be *assigned*.

Instead, use a pointer, initialize that with the address of the first element of the array, make pointer arithmetic on that pointer and store the updated result back to the pointer.